# "Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found" when loading XLSX file

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I've used Apache POI successfully on Java desktop app, and would like to use it on Android for reading & writing Excel files.

Here's my Github repo:
https://github.com/anta40/StockChecker

Everytime I try to open an XLSX file, eventually the app crashes because of

> org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider
>   com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found

Here's the content of my build.gradle:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.anta40.app.stockchecker"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17'
    implementation 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Adding this line on build.gradle:

> implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.1.0'

doesn't work. You'll get lots of error messages like these:

> Duplicate class
>   org.codehaus.stax2.ri.typed.ValueDecoderFactory$IntDecoder found in
>   modules poi-3.17.jar (com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17) and
>   stax2-api-4.1.jar (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.1) Duplicate
>   class org.codehaus.stax2.ri.typed.ValueDecoderFactory$IntegerDecoder
>   found in modules poi-3.17.jar
>   (com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17) and stax2-api-4.1.jar
>   (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.1) Duplicate class
>   org.codehaus.stax2.ri.typed.ValueDecoderFactory$LongArrayDecoder found
>   in modules poi-3.17.jar (com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17)
>   and stax2-api-4.1.jar (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.1) Duplicate
>   class org.codehaus.stax2.ri.typed.ValueDecoderFactory$LongDecoder
>   found in modules poi-3.17.jar
>   (com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17) and stax2-api-4.1.jar
>   (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.1) Duplicate class
>   org.codehaus.stax2.ri.typed.ValueDecoderFactory$QNameDecoder found in
>   modules poi-3.17.jar (com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17) and
>   stax2-api-4.1.jar (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.1) Duplicate
>   class org.codehaus.stax2.ri.typed.ValueEncoderFactory found in modules
>   poi-3.17.jar (com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:3.17) and
>   stax2-api-4.1.jar (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.1)

Answer (score 10):

exculde this stax2-api-4.1.jar in your dependency and rebuild the project

Edit 1- I know i am a bit late with the edit, but solved it just now, just move your System.properties in a static block where you initialize your app. This will solve your problem.

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      //scope......
      static {
            System.setProperty(
                    "org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory",
                    "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl"
            );
            System.setProperty(
                    "org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory",
                    "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl"
            );
            System.setProperty(
                    "org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory",
                    "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl"
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just include these dependencies in your build.gradle module:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.17'
implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', name: 'xmlbeans', version: '3.1.0'
implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.2.2'
```

Don't go with the latest versions of the dependencies as they will generate more errors.

Comment: Perfect combination, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for **Animesh Sharma** for the answer.

However you should extend the Application class and add it there to avoid any code repeating.

```
class AppController : Application() {

    init {
        System.setProperty(
            "org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory",
            "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl"
        );
        System.setProperty(
            "org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory",
            "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl"
        );
        System.setProperty(
            "org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory",
            "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl"
        );
    }
}
```

also do not forget to add it to the **manifest**.
in the  **block** add
**android:name=".AppController"**